# Getting parent of matched element with jsonpath

Tags: javascript, jsonpath

Let's say I have a JSON object such as this:

```
[{
    name: "A",
    sub: [
        {prop: "1"},
        {prop: "2"},
        {prop: "3"},
    ]
},
{
    name: "B",
    sub: [
        {prop: "7"},
        {prop: "8"},
        {prop: "9"},
    ]    
}];
```

How can I get the parent of the element who's `prop` value is `2`?

```
jsonpath.query(data, "$..[?(@.prop==2)]");
```

This will return the object itself, but I don't know how to get it's parent.

Comment: Have you tried `.parent`?

Comment: @Jan `$..[?(@.prop==2)].parent` returns an empty array. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `parent` instead of `query` method. As simple as that. I just missed it when I was reading the docs.