# JSONPath get the id of a parent element by a sub-child value

Tags: json, jsonpath

Given the following JSON I want to get the `id` field of the parent by an equals text compare of a sub-child element:

```
{
    "datapoints": [{
            "id": "default.1",
            "definedBy": "default/0.1",
            "featureValues": {
                "bui.displayname": "Health status",
                "bui.visibility": "normal",
                "default.access": "r",
                "default.basetype": "text",
                "default.description": "Aggregated health status",
                "default.format": "text/plain",
                "default.name": "health_status",
                "default.restriction": "re:(OK|WARN|ERROR|UNKNOWN)"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "kdl.240",
            "definedBy": "kdl/0.9",
            "featureValues": {
                "bui.displayname": "Delta K",
                "bui.visibility": "normal",
                "default.access": "rw",
                "default.basetype": "real",
                "default.description": "Delta K",
                "default.name": "Delta_K",
                "default.privacy": "false",
                "default.restriction": "b32"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My first goal is to get the correct data point by a sub-child text compare like:

`$['datapoints'][*]['featureValues'][?(@['default.name']=='Delta_K')]`

It seems not to work when I test it on http://jsonpath.com/
To get all the data points I used this successfully:

`$['datapoints'][*]['featureValues']['default.name']`

My goal is to get the `id` value of the data point with the `featureValues` child element `default.name` is equal `Delta_K`. In the example this would be `kdl.240`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is working for me on https://jsonpath.com :

```
$.datapoints[?(@.featureValues['default.name']=='Delta_K')].id
```

Comment: It's quite a while since I originally asked that question. It seems that this is possible with your query tested on https://jsonpath.com to get what I wanted back then. I'll set it as the correct answer.

Comment: how will you resolve if you have one more layer of json like   "name" : [
                        {
                            "brand": "apple"
                        }
                    ], inside each department where i want to return if brand name == apple.

Comment: i provided an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76670888/2254425. Hope this help!

Answer (score 7):

I could only solve the first part of my question by using:

```
$['datapoints'][*][?(@['default.name']=='Delta_K')]
```

During my research I found that jsonpath does not support to get the parent of a filtered node. In Chapter 7 "Conclusion" of http://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath it's written:

> Although JsonPath has some drawbacks, such as a lack of operators for reaching ***parent*** or sibling nodes, it can be highly useful in a lot of scenarios.

Also further SO posts couldn't help me.

- [Getting parent of matched element with jsonpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226500/getting-parent-of-matched-element-with-jsonpath)
- [Using jsonpath to get parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878757/using-jsonpath-to-get-parent-node)

Comment: thank you; at least i know what i can do and can not do.

Comment: @user528025 it seems there is an answer now. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73249047/1306012

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a node containing a featureValues attribute that contains a default.name attribute that matches your text.  Using the suggestion at the end of https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287 you can get what you want with:

`$..[?(@.featureValues[?(@['default.name']=='Delta_K')] empty false)].id`

Comment: Acfually, the accepted answer of `$.datapoints[?(@.featureValues['default.name']=='Delta_K')].id` is much better.

Answer (score 0):

```
#cat jsonData.json | jq ‘.datapoints[].featureValues | select .default.name == 'Delta_K') | .id’
```

see also:
https://github.com/adriank/ObjectPath/issues/70