# jmeter: I want to extract 2 values from 2 different json objects where 1 json object will validate my condition & other value I want to extract

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, extractor

My JSON Response is :

```
{
"results": [
    {
      "attributes": [
        {
          "format": "internal",
          "name": "resourceid",
          "type": "STRING",
          "value": "56B15190000015E85E57923F0000033B"
        },        
        {
          "format": "attribute",
          "name": "ds6w:identifier",
          "type": "string",
          "value": "ald7_al"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "attributes": [
        {
          "format": "internal",
          "name": "resourceid",
          "type": "STRING",
          "value": "56B15190000015E85E578B1F000001B6"
        },        
        {
          "format": "attribute",
          "name": "ds6w:identifier",
          "type": "string",
          "value": "fbh1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "attributes": [
        {
          "format": "internal",
          "name": "resourceid",
          "type": "STRING",
          "value": "56B15190000015E85E578F7800000211"
        },
        {
          "format": "attribute",
          "name": "ds6w:identifier",
          "type": "string",
          "value": "u89cf"
        }
      ]
    }    
  ]
}
```

I want to get '56B15190000015E85E57923F0000033B' where value='ald7_al'

So basically within a jsonarray I have jsonobjects, and for single jsonobject I have two jsonobjects where secong jsonobject will validate my condition param and I want value from first jsonobject

For getting result to solve condition check I have used
JSON extractor expression as -> $..attributes[?(@.value==ald7_al)] which is giving me second json block but I want value from first json block.

Please help me if you have any inputs. 
Thanking you in advance for your help!

Comment: It seems there is [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45546171/3832970) to access the parent of the found node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) this it not possible with built-in JMeter components

- [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) cannot do this due to underlying [Jayway JsonPath issue 287](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287)
- [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) cannot do this due to underlying [JMESPath issue 22](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.js/issues/22)

So you're left with [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language, example code which should resolve your issue would be something like:

```
def results = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).results

0.upto(results.size() - 1, { index ->
    def attributes = results[index].attributes
    if (attributes[1].get('value').equals('ald7_al')) {
        vars.put('value', attributes[0].get('value'))
    }
})
```

Add it as a child of the request which returns the above JSON and if everything goes well you will able to access the value you're looking for as `${value}` where required.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)