# JsonPath expression returning a sibling of the parent after filtering on parent's child

Tags: java, json, expression, jsonpath

I'm trying to write a JsonPath expression returning a sibling of the parent after filtering on parent's child. Hers's the JSON:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "date":"2018-10-16T00:00:00.000Z",
         "home_team_score":105,
         "visitor_team_score":87,
         "season":2018,
         "period":4,
         "status":"Final",
         "time":" ",
         "postseason":false,
         "home_team":{
            "id":2,
            "abbreviation":"BOS",
            "city":"Boston",
            "conference":"East",
            "division":"Atlantic",
            "full_name":"Boston Celtics",
            "name":"Celtics"
         },
         "visitor_team":{
            "id":23,
            "abbreviation":"PHI",
            "city":"Philadelphia",
            "conference":"East",
            "division":"Atlantic",
            "full_name":"Philadelphia 76ers",
            "name":"76ers"
         }
      },
      "..."
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the home team score and visitor team score where the home_team city = 'Boston'. Here's my JsonPath expression:

`$..[?(@.home_team.city=='Boston')]`

This is what I've got so far but nothing I've tried works and I've been using https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ to test out new ones but I just don't get it. I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you share a more accurate json format? If data is confidential, you can use examples. Someone who knows json path expression would find it easier to guide.

Comment: Unfortunately JsonPath doesn't support this. As you can see from this [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath#conclusion), **JsonPath has some drawbacks, such as a lack of operators for reaching parent or sibling nodes**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSONPath get the id of a parent element by a sub-child value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543003/jsonpath-get-the-id-of-a-parent-element-by-a-sub-child-value)

Comment: @RavindraHV, I have [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25683950) with a clearer JSON.